# Using JQuery selector inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to select the value of a field in a form to use in my script. The structure of the form is dynamic and allows the user to have sections and fields inside those sections.

[image: This is how the form looks.]

[image: This is what the console looks like after running the current script]
Each input has a unique id, the section title has an id of #(section number)title and the field titles have ids of #(section number),(field number)title.

In this case the first field title would have the ID '#1,1title'.

I am using a for loop to select the sections and then another for loop inside the last one to select each field inside the section.

When I use the loop variable for the sections inside a jQuery selector it works perfectly however when I use the variable for the fields it spits out an error - here's my code for selecting the fields:

```
function buildCourse() {
    //get main course details
    let courseTitle = $('#courseTitle').val();
    let courseDesc = $('#courseDesc').val();
    console.log("Title: " + courseTitle);
    console.log("Description: " + courseDesc);
    //get sections
    let secNum = $('#formdiv').children().length;
    for (let i = 1;i <= secNum; i++){
        //get section details
        let secTitle = $('#' + i + 'title').val();
        let secDesc = $('#' + i + 'desc').val();
        console.log("Section Title: " + secTitle);
        console.log("Section Description: " + secDesc);
        //get field details
        let section = $('#' + i + 'sectionDiv');
        let fieldNum = section.children().length;
        console.log("Section " + i + " has " + fieldNum + " fields");
        for (let f = 1;f <= fieldNum;f++){
            let title = "#" + i + "," + f + "title";
            console.log(title);
            console.log($(title));
        }
    }
}
```

When I do 'console.log($(title).val());' on that last line it logs 'undefined' and when I run it as it is it gives me 'E.fn.init [prevObject: E.fn.init(1)]'. However the console.log just before that where I just log the 'title' variable logs #1,1title as it should. The problem starts when I try and use that variable in the jQuery selector. Any ideas on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: _"Each input has a unique id,..."_ - Why? Ids are for unique elements. But there are clearly multiple sections and fields (each with a title and a description). Use common classes and this will make it so much easier (e.g. you don't have to escape your selector)

Comment: @skobaljic _"You cannot select element by id or class in jQuery if it has comma"_ - You [absolutely can](https://jsfiddle.net/n0zmuLb6/), but you have to escape the selector -> [`$.escapeSelector()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

Comment: Sorry if my helpful comment disturbed you, have a nice day - deleted.